# No static method G()Landroid/content/Intent; when try to receive message from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: com.myfirebase.main, PID: 30567
                                                                        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method G()Landroid/content/Intent; in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver' appears in /data/app/com.riseandshine.risenshine-2/base.apk)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzae(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3088)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:170)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1539)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
```

This error is comming when I am trying to use firebase messaging service. I have tried to find the solution, but could not get it.

My question is... is there anyone who faced the same problem as mine?

And also, What is the method G() used for?

Please help.

Comment: Which version are you using ?

Comment: check that you are using the same version of all the firebase and google play services dependencies. that is a requirement.